# Find all files in a Accurev stream committed by a user

Tags: accurev

I need to find all files in an accurev stream committed by a user. The files could be in sub-directories as well so I need to do a recursive find. I have bean trying from commandline 'accurev hist' command but not able to get what I want. Can any one please help.

Answer (score 2):

This may give you what you want.  Let's assume that the stream name is "Common" and you're trying to find what elements user testuser1 promoted into the stream.

First, generate a listing of all your elements along with their paths.  Run an 'accurev stat -fl -a -s Common > /tmp/list.out' to get a listing in /tmp/list.out.

To see just the elements that user "testuser1" promoted into stream "Common":

'accurev hist -t now -k promote -s Common -u testuser1 -l /tmp/list.out > /tmp/testuser1CommonPromotes.out'

The output when you use the -u switch is rather cumbersome because the command prints out information as it processes each element, adding the user information when there's a match.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write a script to accomplish this.

The stat and hist command should give you all the information you need.